# Astropy Cutout2D, raise ValueError

Tags: python, extract, valueerror, astropy, fits

I am trying to use ***Astropy's Cutout2D*** testing the [presented procedure](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/nddata/utils.html). My goal is to extract a .png image for every source I have in the ground truth catalogue, using RA and DEC.

The headers for the file:

```
SIMPLE  =                    T  /                                               
BITPIX  =                  -32  /                                               
NAXIS   =                    4  /                                               
NAXIS1  =                30000  /                                               
NAXIS2  =                30000  /                                               
NAXIS3  =                    1  /                                               
NAXIS4  =                    1  /                                               
EXTEND  =                    T  /                                               
BSCALE  =    1.00000000000E+00  /                                               
BZERO   =    0.00000000000E+00  /                                               
BLANK   =                   -1  /                                               
BUNIT   = 'JY/BEAM '  /                                                         
DATE-OBS= '2000-01-01T12:00:00.0'  /                                            
CRPIX1  =    1.63840000000E+04  /                                               
CDELT1  =   -6.71387000000E-05  /                                               
CRVAL1  =    0.00000000000E+00  /                                               
CTYPE1  = 'RA---SIN'  /                                                         
CRPIX2  =    1.63840000000E+04  /                                               
CDELT2  =    6.71387000000E-05  /                                               
CRVAL2  =   -3.00000000000E+01  /                                               
CTYPE2  = 'DEC--SIN'  /                                                         
CRPIX3  =    1.00000000000E+00  /                                               
CDELT3  =    4.20000000000E+08  /                                               
CRVAL3  =    1.40000000000E+09  /                                               
CTYPE3  = 'FREQ    '  /                                                         
CRPIX4  =    1.00000000000E+00  /                                               
CDELT4  =    1.00000000000E+00  /                                               
CRVAL4  =    1.00000000000E+00  /                                               
CTYPE4  = 'STOKES  '  /        
...
```

I use this small script copied from documentation:

```
hdu = fits.open(file)[0]
data=hdu.data
w = WCS(file)
    position = SkyCoord(24.17*u.deg, 15.78*u.deg,frame='fk5',equinox='J2000.0'  
    size = u.Quantity((10,10), u.arcsec)  
    cutout = Cutout2D(data, posit

ion, size, fill_value=np.nan,  wcs=w)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "###/Cutoff_patches.py", line 113, in <module>
    cutout = Cutout2D(data, position, size,   wcs=w)
  File "##_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/nddata/utils.py", line 686, in __init__
    return_position=True)
  File "##_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/nddata/utils.py", line 211, in extract_array
    shape, position, mode=mode)
  File "##_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/nddata/utils.py", line 91, in overlap_slices
    raise ValueError('"large_array_shape" and "small_array_shape" must '
ValueError: "large_array_shape" and "small_array_shape" must have the same number of dimensions.
```

I have no idea why that happens and how to solve it.

I also tried reshape as mentioned:

```
data = data.reshape(data.shape[2:])
```

and also,

```
data=np.squeeze(data)
```

but then I get the same for both of them:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "##/Cutoff_patches.py", line 114, in <module>
    cutout = Cutout2D(data, position, size,   wcs=w)
  File "##venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/nddata/utils.py", line 686, in __init__
    return_position=True)
  File "/##_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/nddata/utils.py", line 211, in extract_array
    shape, position, mode=mode)
  File "##_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/nddata/utils.py", line 106, in overlap_slices
    raise NoOverlapError('Arrays do not overlap.')
astropy.nddata.utils.NoOverlapError: Arrays do not overlap.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Where is the error raised? You need to post the full stack

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link at the bottom of your post. Please put the full traceback in the post and make sure it's formatted properly so as to be more legible.

Comment: I see now looking at your FITS header that it's a 4-D array, but two of the dimensions are of size 1. Try just `data = data.reshape(data.shape[2:])`

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the FITS file to a 2D image then the **Cutout2D** will work easier:

```
hdu = fits.open(file)[0]
data = hdu.data[0,0,:,:]   # checkout image data
# modify header keywords
hdu.header['NAXIS'] = 2
hdu.header['WCSAXES']=2
# delete all keywords of additional axis
del hdu.header['NAXIS3']
del hdu.header['NAXIS4']
del hdu.header['CRPIX3']
...

w = WCS(hdu.header)
position = SkyCoord(24.17*u.deg, 15.78*u.deg,frame='fk5',equinox='J2000.0') 
size = u.Quantity((10,10), u.arcsec)  
cutout = Cutout2D(data, position, size, fill_value=np.nan,  wcs=w)
```